# One Parameter of HTTP Response to Another HTTP request in JMETER

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In JMeter,

I have One Thread , Say T1 and it has 4 HTTP requests. Say HR1 to HR4.

I fed some data via parameterization to HR1 and I need one value from the response of HTTP request of HR1 and I need to pass it to HR2 and later HR4.

I tried Extractor's and BeanShell expression. But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer.

I Took the "Regular Expression Extractor" from the response and put it under the first HTTP request.

In the Second HTTP request, i called the that one and it worked like Magic :)

Thanks.